# String matches method to get words beginning with specified letters in Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, iteration

I am using ArrayList to hold a list of strings, and I am iterating through the ArrayList and trying to return words that starts with a string ( user input ).

My code:

```
private void doP( ArrayList <String> words, String cmd3 )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++ )
    {
        if( words.get( i ).matches( cmd3 + "(.*)" ))
        {
            tempString.add( words.get( i ));
            System.out.println( "H:" + words.get( i ));
        }
    }

    System.out.println( tempString );
```

The code works properly if I replace ( cmd3 + "(.* )" ) with ( "th(.*)" ).
I think the problem here is the format, and I really can't figure this out.

Sorry for using non-descriptive terms, I have just started programming 2 months ago...

TLDR;

```
if( words.get( i ).matches( cmd3 + "(.*)" ))
```

This is the problem, specifically with ( cmd3 + (.* )). My logic in this is that any string the user input with (.*) at the end should work, so like for example, if the user types "ABCD" then I should have:

```
if( words.get( i ).matches( "ABCD(.*)" ))
```

Thanks!

PS: startsWith() method does the job, and it was a very minor mistake on my part. Thanks to everyone who answered.

Comment: `The code works properly if I replace ( cmd3 + "(.* )" ) with ( "th(.*)" )` Prove it. Show us input and expected/actual output.

Comment: You know that you are creating a regular expression to match something right? Also, your regular expression say (for ABCD) that you have to have a element in your list that matches ABCD+anythingelse

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanos - I have a file.txt given my teacher, and in one part I have to create an ArrayList and in it is a list of words starting with the letter/letter(s) t, th respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it seems that you are trying to reinvent [`startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Try maybe

```
if( words.get(i).startsWith(cmd3))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because .matches is using a regular expression and so it is looking exactly for the value of cmd3.

I don't want to get too detailed into regular expressions and confuse you but the part with (.*) works because it is basically adding "zero or more of any character"

I think .startWith(cmd3) will work better for you.

You can read about .starsWith() [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `startsWith(str)` method:

```
private static void doP(ArrayList<String> words, String cmd3)
{
    ArrayList<String> tempString = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
    {
        if (words.get(i).startsWith(cmd3))
        {
            tempString .add(words.get(i));
            System.out.println("H:" + words.get(i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(tempString.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    strings.add("ABCDE");
    strings.add("ABCDEFG");
    strings.add("BCDE");
    doP(strings, "ABC");
}
```

Comment: I should have been more specific in my question, but basically I have to sort a file into an ArrayList and within it is a list of words that I have to seperate. specifically words with the letter t, and th. 

And I think startsWith only takes the first letter in a string, so startsWith( "th" ) don't work. Unless I am wrong.

Comment: PS: Ok my bad, you are right, It was my mistake within my code. I had startsWith() at first but wasnt getting the right output because of a minor confusion, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the method you posted here, it does not seem to have any issue, I only had to put the declaration for tempString in your method

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test {     
public static void main(String a[] ) {   
  ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(); 
  arr.add("ABCD");
  arr.add("EFGH");
  arr.add("ABYZ");
  doP(arr, "AB");
}

private static void doP( ArrayList <String> words, String cmd3 )
{
    ArrayList<String> tempString = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for( int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++ )
    {
        if( words.get( i ).matches( cmd3 + "(.*)" ))
        {
            tempString.add( words.get( i ));
            System.out.println( "H:" + words.get( i ));
        }
    }

    System.out.println( tempString );
}
}
```

On running this it produced the following output

```
H:ABCD
H:ABYZ
[ABCD, ABYZ]
```

Is this not what you expect in the output ? So what is the real issue here ?